# Issue Adding The Output Of 2 Functions In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building 2 sliders for a client and need to be able to add the result of each together and display it in the cost section. I am able to create the 2 slider separately but am struggling to get them to work together.

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output1 = document.getElementById("guests");
var output2 = document.getElementById("hours");
var price = document.getElementById("cost");

slider1.oninput = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}
document.getElementById("guests", "hours").addEventListener("oninput", function() {
  price.innerHTML = output1.textContent + output2.textContent;
})
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider1,
.slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #8300e9;
  outline: none;
}

.slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb,
.slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider1::-moz-range-thumb,
.slider2::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Guests: <span id="guests"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="250" value="0" step="10" class="slider1" id="myRange1">
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <p>Hours: <span id="hours"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p><input type="range" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider2" id="myRange2"></p>

  <br>

  <p>Cost: <span id="cost"></span></p>
</div>
```

The cost section needs to add the guests and hours together.

Comment: `price.innerHTML = output1.innerText + output2.innerText;`

Comment: First of all replace `output1.value` and `output2.value` to the `output1.textContent` and `output2.textContent`. After doing so, put this part `price.innerHTML = output1.textContent + output2.textContent;` in some event as according to your example this line will run when your site is loaded so it does nothing cause `output1.textContent` and `output2.textContent` don't have any value yet.

Comment: @Konrud Thanks a lot for your reply. I have replaced ```price.innerHTML = output1.value + output2.value;``` with ```price.innerHTML = output1.textContent + output2.textContent;``` but I am not too sure what you mean by the second part of your response.

Comment: I have made some adjustments to the JavaScript code above but am still not there yet. I can't get both sliders to add the 2 values together and display it in the cost section.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle events, This will do the work

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output1 = document.getElementById("guests");
var output2 = document.getElementById("hours");
var price = document.getElementById("cost");
var totalCost = 0;

slider1.oninput = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = this.value;
  callSum();
}

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
  callSum();
}

var callSum = function(value) {
   if (parseInt(output1.textContent) && parseInt(output2.textContent)) {
    price.innerHTML = 250 + 20 * (parseInt(output1.textContent) /10 -1) + parseInt(output2.textContent) * 10;
  }
 
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider1,
.slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #8300e9;
  outline: none;
}

.slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb,
.slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider1::-moz-range-thumb,
.slider2::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Guests: <span id="guests"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="250" value="0" step="10" class="slider1" id="myRange1">
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <p>Hours: <span id="hours"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p><input type="range" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider2" id="myRange2"></p>

  <br>

  <p>Cost: <span id="cost"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That works nicely. Thanks ever so much! The last issue I now have is that the client wants a £250 starting cost when the guest slider hits 10. it needs to add £20 to each amount of hours they drag it across to. I have made the necessary changes to the code but how I have done it, it adds an additional £1 because of the way the code is written. An example would be Guests = 10, Hours = 1 which = £281 when should be £270 because £250 should start when it hits 10 Guests. I have updated my latest code.

Comment: What would be the cost when the guest is less then 10 ??

Comment: If the sliders have not been dragged across, the value should not show anything. If the Guest slider has been dragged across to 10, the Cost should be £250. When the Guest slider is moved to 20, the Cost should be £270 and so on. Each time the Hours slider is moved to the next notch, it should add £10 to the total cost. I made an edit to the answer with what I have added so far, its awaiting peer review.

Comment: Please check now. I have rejected your suggestion and edited mine

Comment: One thing I have noticed is when you move the sliders back to the start, the Cost doesn't go back to 0.